# writing out a character value inserting indentation when there is special character in r

Tags: r, text, save

I am working on character values and I need to write them out. Here is how my sample values look like:

```
items <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5")
group <- c(paste0("Items = ",paste0(items, collapse=", "), ";"), #Items
           paste0(paste0("Codes(", items, ") = 0(0), 1(1)",collapse="; ", sep=""),";"), #Codes
           paste0(paste("Model(", items, ") = 2PL",collapse="; ", sep=""),";"))

> group
[1] "Items = A1, A2, A3, A4, A5;"                                                                                            
[2] "Codes(A1) = 0(0), 1(1); Codes(A2) = 0(0), 1(1); Codes(A3) = 0(0), 1(1); Codes(A4) = 0(0), 1(1); Codes(A5) = 0(0), 1(1);"
[3] "Model(A1) = 2PL; Model(A2) = 2PL; Model(A3) = 2PL; Model(A4) = 2PL; Model(A5) = 2PL;"    

cat(group, file = "test.irtpro")
```

When I write it out, everthing is on one line. However, I need an indendation when there is `;` at the end. So the desired output that is written in the outfile should be:

```
Items = A1, A2, A3, A4, A5;                                                                                            
Codes(A1) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A2) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A3) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A4) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A5) = 0(0), 1(1);
Model(A1) = 2PL; 
Model(A2) = 2PL; 
Model(A3) = 2PL; 
Model(A4) = 2PL; 
Model(A5) = 2PL;
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
cat(unlist(strsplit(group, "(?<=;\\s)", perl = TRUE)), file = "test.irtpro", sep = "\n")
```

This will split strings by semicolon (keeping the semicolon, but leaving out the space afterwards), and use newline `\n` at each split.

**test.irtpro**

```
Items = A1, A2, A3, A4, A5;
Codes(A1) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A2) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A3) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A4) = 0(0), 1(1); 
Codes(A5) = 0(0), 1(1);
Model(A1) = 2PL; 
Model(A2) = 2PL; 
Model(A3) = 2PL; 
Model(A4) = 2PL; 
Model(A5) = 2PL;
```